# Discord Bot not correctly reading .json Database

Tags: json, discord.js

I am attempting to build a discord bot, and one of its features is that it will be able to recognize whether a user has interacted with the bot before by using a json array database. What is instead happening is that it does not read the array, and writes the username into the file even if it is already in the database.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const { json } = require('stream/consumers');
const {prefix, token} = require('./config.json');
const {recognizedusers} = require('./database.json');

//Read File
let db = fs.readFileSync('./database.json');
db = JSON.parse(db);

// New discord client
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });



//Client run once
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

//Client always run code
client.on('message', message => {
    let msg_content = message.content.toLowerCase()

    // Mixed message content response
    if (msg_content.includes('test 1') && msg_content.includes('test 2')) {
        message.channel.send('test 2: electric boogaloo')
    }

    if (msg_content.includes('test') && !message.author.username.includes(db.recognizedusers)) {

        message.channel.send('unrecognized name')

        //Edit Variable
        db.recognizedusers.push(message.author.username)

        // write file
        fs.writeFileSync('./database.json', JSON.stringify(db));
    }

});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: I think you ment `!db.recognizedusers.includes(message.author.username)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elitezen fixed my problem.

> I think you ment `!db.recognizedusers.includes(message.author.username)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).